# COUNTIF formula displaying 0 until clicking into cell, and clicking out again

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

I have a COUNTIF formula, which is supposed to count whether or not the cells in that row contain an “x” (=COUNTIF(Q54:AAA54,“x”)). It’s inserted automatically into that row using a macro. When I run the macro, it does insert the formula into the column correctly, but initially it isn’t counting the “x”s, it’s just saying zero for everything:

[image]

But if I double click into the cell and then click away again, it does do the calculations:

[image]

My code is below:

```
Range("L4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=COUNTIF(RC[5]:RC[691],""x"")"
Range("L4").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L4:L" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Does anyone know why the formula isn’t initially counting the “x”s? Is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks very much

Comment: Do you have calculation set to automatic?

Comment: I did not! Fixed, thank you so much